# Kindle Touch Battery Replacement

Tags: kindle, hardware, battery

Can I replace the internal battery of my Kindle Touch. How do I go about this? What battery does it use? Where can I find a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While changing your battery is an option.  I would recommend contacting Kindle support first. Even if the warranty has expired, free or low cost replacement devices can be had.  In my experience, there are multiple levels of support.  When I first called, someone speaking English as a second language was giving answers from helpdesk answer book, (not so helpful).  They offered, or I asked to talk to kindle support (don't recall exactly) and I was transferred to a person who seemed to have language and kindle familiarity in common with me.

I received an refurbished kindle keyboard in the mail a couple days later. Had a few days grace to transfer non-amazon content from the old to the new. I mailed it back (postage paid by amazon I think) and all is well.

I have heard of others who had an older device be offered great deals on refurbished device and been happy with the outcome.  It's a free call, so nothing to loose.  Put 'kindle support' in the search window at Amazon.com and go from there.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, [this youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmwQbc6TWMg) video has the tutorial and the description has the link for the resource for a new battery.

And [here you can find](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/cracking-open/amazon-kindle-touch-2011-teardown-replaceable-battery-neonode-touch-screen/) a proper hardware analysis of the device.

Battery info: `3.7V, 1,420mAh (5.25Wh) Li-ion Polymer Battery (Model: S2011-002-A)`